# How to show a single Item in cakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, loops, slider

I am using cake PHP and on my **view/technical_slider/index.ctp** is the following:
I am using a heavily modified version of this tutorial [Featured Content Slider Using jQuery](http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/featured-content-slider/)

```
<?php foreach ($technicalSlides as $technicalSlide):?>
<div id="nav-fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel">

<h2><?php echo $technicalSlide['TechnicalSlide']['title'];?></h2>
<p><?php echo $technicalSlide['TechnicalSlide']['description'] ; ?></p>

</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My question is: How can I display only certain id's or items and apply different class on the same div ? Because I only want record 1-3 skip 4-7 then show record 8-15?

I am applying different classes on them because they have different backgrounds, but share the same id.

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter variable (in this case `$i`), increment it (`$i++`) so it increases by one for every loop, and add your checks to an `if()` block to make sure you only write the ones you want to:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach ($technicalSlides as $technicalSlide):
    if($i < 4 || $i > 7) {
        ?>
        <div id="nav-fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel">

        <h2><?php echo $technicalSlide['TechnicalSlide']['title'];?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $technicalSlide['TechnicalSlide']['description'] ; ?></p>

        </div>
        <?php
    }
    $i++;
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You coud add a counter and then display only those you want.

```
 <?php int $i = 0; ?>
 <?php foreach ($technicalSlides as $technicalSlide):?>
 <?php if ($i < 4 || $i > 7): ?>
   <div id="nav-fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel">

   <h2><?php echo $technicalSlide['TechnicalSlide']['title'];?></h2>
   <p><?php echo $technicalSlide['TechnicalSlide']['description'] ; ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>

 </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Although I would merge all classes and use attributes.